# Error when I call a partial view with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, partial-views

How can I call a partial view with ajax?

I'm using the following code but it gives an error :

```
$('#Get').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUser","Users")',
        data: { no: 10 },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            // status = Error
        },
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {

        }
    });
});
```

my action Result :

```
public ActionResult GetUser(int no)
{
    var User=new AllUsers
    {
        UserName = "test"
    };
    return PartialView("_GetUser",User);
}
```

error : **Internal Server Error**

Comment: There is no answer?? please help me

Comment: Maybe `data: {"no": 10 },`